# ¿Cómo trabajo una variable php en la función fopen?

Tags: php, csv, highcharts, fopen

Tengo una variable en php llamada $url, que es una url construida con texto y variables que vienen desde un formulario, y que leen un csv:

```
<?php $url = "http://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.tsindico.cgi?outtype=xcl&page=pageFrame&header=Coyhaique".htmlspecialchars($especial)."opath=./RXI/".$_POST["e_cod"]."/Cal/".$_POST["mat"].htmlspecialchars($especial)."o=./RXI/".$_POST["e_cod"]."/Cal/".$_POST["mat"]."/".$_POST["mat"].".horario.horario.ic&from=".$date_from_final.$_POST["hora_desde"]."00&to=".$date_to_final.$_POST["hora_hasta"]."00&path=/usr/airviro/data/CONAMA/&";?>
```

El siguiente código lo que hace es abrir el archivo (csv desde una url), y si el valor comienza por un numero lo imprime, sino imprime null.

Lo que quiero hacer es que la funcion fopen sea capaz de trabajar con esa url, cosa que no hace. Si ingreso por ejemplo 'datos.csv' lo lee sin problemas, pero la variable $url no.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php $numeros = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
        if (($handle = fopen('$url', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[3] == '' OR !in_array($data[3][0], $numeros)){
            $data[3] = 'null';}
        print_r($data[3].",");
    }
    fclose($handle);}?>
```

Comment: Intenta usando comillas dobles en lugar de simples `"$url"`

Comment: Y tu código que error te da exactamente?

Comment: @alanfcm Tampoco, solo imprime un solo null.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Ninguno, simplemente no imprime nada.

Comment: Y esa url conduce exactamente al csv? Yo no estoy segura de si puedas construir esa url de esa forma. Pero al parecer el fopen() está fallando al abrir el archivo. Prueba poner un else despues del primer if a ver si entra

Comment: El único problema que tienes es lo que ya comentó @alanfcm. Al hacer esto: `if (($handle = fopen('$url', 'r')) !== FALSE) {`,  al usar comillas simples para la variable `$url`, PHP no la reconoce como tal, por tanto lo que estás pasando es esto literalmente `$url` y no el valor real de la variable. En caso de necesitar usar el valor real de una variable dentro de comillas, éstas tienen que ser comillas dobles. Pero aquí tampoco las necesitas, ¿por qué no pones simplemente: `if (($handle = fopen($url, 'r')) !== FALSE) {` ? Si quieres probar lo que te digo haz:  `echo '$url';`  y `echo "$url";`.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Era un problema en las "" de la variable y en la conformación de la misma, ya que en ella debía omitir el htmlspecialchars para que así la función fopen la pudiese leer bien.

Comment: @A.Cedano Era un problema en las "" de la variable y en la conformación de la misma, ya que en ella debía omitir el htmlspecialchars para que así la función fopen la pudiese leer bien. Mas abajo explico con mas detalle el problema que tenía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné. La variable $url debía estar entre "" quedando "$url", pero no solo eso, tenia un problema en la conformación de la variable, ya que en ella debía omitir el htmlspecialchars para que así la función fopen la pudiese leer bien.

Gracias a todos.